# Plot bar graph using table data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

### I am trying to plot this kind of graph using pgfplots here is my code:

it is showing error pls help me
[image]

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Year,
        ylabel=No. of Ques]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
(CD,0)
(CN,0)
(CO,0)
(DA,0)
(DBMS,0)
(DLD,0)
(DM,0)
(EM,1)
(GEN,0)
(OS,0)
(PROG,1)
(TOC,0)
    };
\addlegendentry{
2015}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to define your coordinates before using them.

Replace

```
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Year,
        ylabel=No. of Ques]
```

with

```
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Year,
        ylabel=No. of Ques,
        symbolic x coords={CD, CN, CO, DA, DBMS, DLD, DM, EM, GEN, OS, PROG, TOC}]
```

to get

[image]

To see all of the x-coordinates, they must have enough space to fit. You will have to enlarge the width of the plot. Solution to this was provided as answer to the question of [How to increase/fit the width of x-axis to fit all points in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99025/how-to-increase-fit-the-width-of-x-axis-to-fit-all-points-in-pgfplots)

Now replace

```
\begin{axis}[
            xlabel=Year,
            ylabel=No. of Ques,
            symbolic x coords={CD, CN, CO, DA, DBMS, DLD, DM, EM, GEN, OS, PROG, TOC}]
```

with

```
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Year,
        ylabel=No. of Ques,
        symbolic x coords={CD, CN, CO, DA, DBMS, DLD, DM, EM, GEN, OS, PROG, TOC},
        enlarge x limits=-1,
        width=13cm] % ADJUST WIDTH TO YOUR LIKING
```

to get

[image]

Here is your code with above modifications **and** a document class declaration (which was absent) in case you run into problems:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Year,
        ylabel=No. of Ques,
        symbolic x coords={CD, CN, CO, DA, DBMS, DLD, DM, EM, GEN, OS, PROG, TOC},
        enlarge x limits=-1,
        width=13cm] % ADJUST WIDTH TO YOUR LIKING
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
(CD,0)
(CN,0)
(CO,0)
(DA,0)
(DBMS,0)
(DLD,0)
(DM,0)
(EM,1)
(GEN,0)
(OS,0)
(PROG,1)
(TOC,0)
    };
\addlegendentry{
2015}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want the exact plot as showed in the picture of your question, you'll have to let pgfplots know that you need a bar plot. You'll also have to provide same values as shown in your picture.

Comment: Why not just add `ybar` to the `axis` options (and remove all the options for the `\addplot`)?